# Change text area content using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

Newbie in `AJAX` here, I want to requery or `select *from` again on my database on button click and change the textarea content? How do I do that using `AJAX`.

Here is my code.

```
<textarea id="CKUPDATEALL">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *FROM home WHERE ANNOUNCE_TYPE='WELCOMENOTE' ORDER BY ANNOUNCE_NUMBER DESC limit 0,1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['ANNOUNCEMENTS'];
}
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: That is your php code, not your ajax/jquery code. Did you try doing anything in these languages or you just want us to do your work/homework? Please find some tutorials and learn more about PHP/HTML/Javascript/Ajax/etc before you try to solve a problem, don't just ask to other people to solve your problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

No you can set your php file to check against different variables being passed in the Ajax call. The in the Ajax response success look for the different variables that were defined in the php file. So you might call Ajax.php for 10 different Ajax calls and responses. Just have to set it up properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#my_button").on('cick',function(){
 Var name = $('#thisinputid').val();
 $.ajax({
     url: "getval.php",
     type: "POST",
     data : { fullname : name },
     success: function(data) {
           $("#CKUPDATEALL").val(data);
     }
});
});
```

Then in the php file check for $_post['fullname'].

Answer (score 0):

Try **[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax)** like,

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'get_announcement.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{type:'announcement'},
      success:funtion(d){
         $('#CKUPDATEALL').val(d);
      }
    });
});
```

**get_announcement.php**

```
<?php
    // type is announcement
    if(isset($_POST['type']) and $_POST['type']=='announcement'){
       $result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM home WHERE 
                 ANNOUNCE_TYPE='WELCOMENOTE' ORDER BY ANNOUNCE_NUMBER DESC limit 1");
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          echo $row['ANNOUNCEMENTS'];
       }
       echo 'not found';
    }
?>
```

Comment: so i will be using 1 php file in every query?How can i use if(isset)?

Comment: @user3177305 now try my answer.

Comment: i finally made it work, i used this simple codes    function opendiagedit(id)
{
 $.post('insert_home.php',{SELECTCHECK:id}).done(function(data){
  
  alert (data);
  });

Comment: what i want to do now is to make the the text area value equal to the data, .val is not working

Comment: **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** is working, check in `console` that you are getting data or not? YOu can use `alert(d);` in `success callback function`. Also Add `connection code` in `get_announcement.php` page

Comment: its alerting the data i want, but its not outputting on the textarea, btw im using ckeditor

Comment: Then check the `id` of `textarea` or the `div` which is `created by ckediter` if it is a `div` then use `$('div#divId').html(d);`

Comment: i remove the ckeditor script but it is still bot working

Comment: i figured it out, thanks  function opendiagedit(id)
{
 $.post('insert_home.php',{SELECTCHECK:id}).done(function(data){
  
 CKEDITOR.instances.CKUPDATEALL.setData( data );
  });

  
    $( "#dialog-edit" ).dialog( "open" );
    numtopost=id;

}

Answer (score 0):

Say this is your button

```
<input type="button" id="my_button" value="Cick"/>
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#my_button").on('cick',function(){
     $.ajax({
         url: "getval.php",
         type: "POST",
         data : {'type':'textarea'},
         success: function(data) {
               $("#CKUPDATEALL").val(data);
         }
  });
});
```

And in getval.php

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['type']) && trim($_POST['type']) == 'textarea'){
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM home WHERE ANNOUNCE_TYPE='WELCOMENOTE' ORDER BY ANNOUNCE_NUMBER DESC limit 0,1");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
       echo $row['ANNOUNCEMENTS'];
    }
    die();
  }
?>
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but i just dot understand this part
data : {'type':'textarea'}, the part for the isset.

Comment: Thats nothing but passing parameters to the server.. the first one is the parameter name and the second one is the value. You can pass more than one parameters using comma seperated values.. like this.... `data : {'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value4'},`